# DependsOn Failing in ARM Template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Im trying to connect our website to a Application Insights component via ARM but havning troubles in setting the Intstrumentation Key as an website application setting. This works sometimes and sometimes not.

My guess is that im having incorrect dependsOn settings. Can anyone have a look on my template and see if im doing something wrong? Have a look on the resource called "appSettings" of type "config" in the website resource. Here I am supposed to wait for completion of the Application Insight and then read the Instrumentation Key.

```
 {
  "name": "[variables('webAppNameFinal')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[parameters('appServicePlanLocation')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('appServicePlanNameFinal'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('appServicePlanNameFinal'))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "webApp"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('webAppNameFinal')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[variables('appServicePlanNameFinal')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
      "name": "connectionstrings",
      "type": "config",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppNameFinal'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerNameFinal'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Watches": {
          "value": "[concat('Server=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerNameFinal'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Database=', variables('sqlDatabaseNameFinal'), ';User ID=', parameters('sqlServerAdminLogin'), ';Password=', parameters('sqlServerAdminLoginPassword'), ';Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;')]",
          "type": "SQLAzure"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "appsettings",
      "type": "config",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppNameFinal'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', variables('applicationInsightsNameFinal'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Watches.Webjobs.VitecConnect.WatchersExport.Run": "false",
        "ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', variables('applicationInsightsNameFinal'))).InstrumentationKey]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
      "name": "web",
      "type": "sourcecontrols",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppNameFinal'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('gitUrl')]",
        "branch": "[parameters('gitBranch')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "web",
      "type": "config",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppNameFinal'))]"
      ],
      "properties": "[variables('siteProperties')]"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsNameFinal')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
  "location": "Central US",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "dependsOn": [ ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Application Insights"
  },
  "properties": {
    "applicationId": "[variables('webAppNameFinal')]"
  }
},
```

Best reagards 
Niclas

Comment: What is the behavior when it doesn't work?  Any errors?

Comment: Hi Ben, the behaviour is that the appsetting im trying to set, "ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey" isnt set att all. The website is created without this key / value.

Comment: I am experiencing similar problems, any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place the dependsOn inside the insight resource declaration?

Have a look at the Quickstart template for a web+sql here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-sql-database/azuredeploy.json

They placed the dependsOn on the Insight declaration and nothing on the website declaration. Would that work for you?

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "name": "[concat('AppInsights', variables('webSiteName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "centralus",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('webSiteName')]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName')))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ApplicationId": "[variables('webSiteName')]"
      }
    }
```